# it's not working DBUnit @DatabaseSetup with CSV loader when included period table name

Tags: java, dbunit

when I use `@DatabaseSetup` in the test.
there is an error "no such table" in the title case.

it's working collect below case.

---

CSV loader

```java
public class CsvDataSetLoader extends AbstractDataSetLoader {
    @Override
    protected IDataSet createDataSet(Resource resource) throws Exception {
        return new CsvDataSet(resource.getFile());
    }
}
```

sql:

```sql
create table test
(
    id int
);
```

table-ordering.txt

```
test
```

test.csv

```
id
1
2
3
```

test class

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DbUnitConfiguration(dataSetLoader = CsvDataSetLoader.class) 
@TestExecutionListeners({
  DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
  DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
@Transactional
public class JsonDatabaseTest {

  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Test
  @DatabaseSetup("/table/init")
  public void test(){
    System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from test"));
    // printed out 1,2,3
  }
}
```

---

but it's happened error 'no such table sh.test'

sql:

```sql
create schema sh;

create table sh.test
(
    id int
);
```

table-ordering.txt

```
sh.test
```

sh.test.csv

```
id
1
2
3
```

test class

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DbUnitConfiguration(dataSetLoader = CsvDataSetLoader.class) 
@TestExecutionListeners({
  DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
  DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
@Transactional
public class JsonDatabaseTest {

  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Test
  @DatabaseSetup("/table/init") // if comment out this, no error occurs
  public void test(){
    System.out.println(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from sh.test"));
  }
}
```

When I comment out the code, no error occurs, so the table named "sh.test" must indeed exist.
but why is `@DatabaseSetup` missing the table? I can't guess.....

Comment: If I change the dataSetLoader to an xml one, the same error occurs. So the reason why this initialization doesn't work seems to be that the schema is specified.

Answer (score 0):

it was simply.

at setting class

```java
  @Bean
  H2Connection h2Connection() throws DatabaseUnitException, SQLException{
    return new H2Connection(dataSource().getConnection(), "sh");
  }
```

at test class

```java
@DbUnitConfiguration(databaseConnection = "h2Connection", dataSetLoader = CsvDataSetLoader.class)
```

Now I don't need to add the schema name to file names, etc.